# MySQL: possible to calculate the total inventory cost based on amount per received order?

Tags: mysql

I would like to calculate the total inventory cost by subtracting received orders till the received order quantity matches the inventory level. This way I will have an accurate cost of the total inventory.

I have the following table for individual order receipt lines. `order_receipt_article`

```
id   order_receipt_id   article_id   quantity   price
1    1000               456          10         100
2    1001               456          5          120
3    1002               456          15         140
4    1003               456          20         100
5    1004               456          5          90
```

And another table for inventory invetory

```
id   article_id   level
1    456          43
```

Now I want the total value of the stock on hand which can be calculated like

(5 x 90) + (20 x 100) + (15 x 140) + (3 x 120) = 4910

I would post what I've already tried but I have no idea where to start to solve this.

/edit

I'm not asking for a basic `SUM()` I have a total of 55 received units but have 43 in stock. I want to know the exact value of the stock based on the received units. So looking at the first table the oldest order (id 1) will not be used in the calculation because within orders 2 t/m 5 I have received a total of 45.

Comment: Please try to find information before posting and asking for a complete solution. Here is a page that can get you started: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/MySQL_Calculations_and_Concatenations

Comment: @PdC have you even read my question? Please tell me the solution, if I had found an answer I wouldn't be here.

Comment: I read your question and I understand your frustration, but googling for "mysql calculation on columns" led to that page. That's less than 3 seconds of work put in. If you take a look around on SO you will notice that it is encouraged to at least do due diligence research. You are basically asking for a solution, and imho, I can't see any research in your post.

Comment: @PdC I'm not asking for a basic SUM() function, I have written many complex SQL queries before but with this I'm can build in in PHP very easy but would like a solution in MySQL. So googling 'MySQL calculations' won't get me anywhere.

Comment: @PdC What is your problem? In the same sentence I'm saying I don't know where to start so there is nothing to show?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152419/discussion-between-bart-and-pdc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your issue, it uses session variables to keep a running total of the number of units processed. Unusually I couldn't get this to work without a temp table as the ordering wasn't working properly, this is the only way I found to solve this issue.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS order_receipt_article_test;
CREATE TABLE order_receipt_article_test(id INT UNSIGNED, order_receipt_id INT UNSIGNED, article_id INT UNSIGNED, quantity INT UNSIGNED, price INT UNSIGNED);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS inventory_test;
CREATE TABLE inventory_test(id INT UNSIGNED, article_id INT UNSIGNED, `level` INT UNSIGNED);

INSERT INTO order_receipt_article_test VALUES
    (1, 1000, 456, 10, 100),
    (2, 1001, 456, 5, 120),
    (3, 1002, 456, 15, 140),
    (4, 1003, 456, 20, 100),
    (5, 1004, 456, 5, 90);

INSERT INTO inventory_test VALUES
    (1, 456, 43);

SET @VArticleId := 0;
SET @VCumulativeQuantity := 0;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS ZSort;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ZSort
SELECT A.article_id, A.`level`, B.quantity, B.price, B.order_receipt_id FROM 
    inventory_test A
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    order_receipt_article_test B
ON A.article_id = B.article_id
ORDER BY A.article_id, B.order_receipt_id DESC;

SELECT article_id, SUM(rowPrice) FROM
    (
    SELECT @VCumulativeQuantity := IF(article_id != @VArticleId, `level`, @VCumulativeQuantity) levelReset, IF(@VCumulativeQuantity < quantity, @VCumulativeQuantity * price, quantity * price) rowPrice, @VCumulativeQuantity := IF(@VCumulativeQuantity < quantity, 0, @VCumulativeQuantity - quantity) quantityAdjust, @VArticleId := article_id article_id FROM ZSort
    ) A
GROUP BY article_id;
```

Regards,

James

Comment: Works perfectly!

Comment: I found out that the temporary table is not necessary instead quering the resultset directly in a subquery gave me the same results. So not sure if that is what you meant with the ordering not working properly.

Comment: Quite possibly, it was a strange ordering issue where it appeared the session variables we're being evaluated first and ordering applied second whereas this should be the other way around. Thanks for letting me know, I'll monitor my server and if I can reproduce I'll post about it